# BULK INSERT SQL SERVER from FTP: Filepath Issue

Tags: sql-server, ftp, filepath

Accidental DBA here:

I have a variety of CSV exports from my UNIX ERP system that I'm trying to fetch from SQL Server 2014 instead of transferring to my local drive and uploading from there. I have to execute the exports from the ERP system which then sends them to FTP. When I use the Bulk Insert commands I get this error:

```
Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

Code for reference:

```
BULK
INSERT [SALES].DBO.[CUSTOMER-MASTER]
FROM '/tmp/export/customer.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

I don't know what the correct file path is nor where to find it. How do I figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path must be either file in the SQL Server's disc, or a windows share (SMB) that the account that the server is running can access using an UNC Path. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx):

> data_file must specify a valid path from the server on which SQL
>   Server is running. If data_file is a remote file, specify the
>   Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name. A UNC name has the form
>   \\Systemname\ShareName\Path\FileName. For example,
>   \\SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\update.txt.